# Why is my quick-sort slower than merge-sort?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, merge

This is my implementation. When I put 100 hundred arrays size 1000000, it sorting for 300 sec.
My another algorithm, merge sort do it for 40 sec.
I wonder, if there are some things that could slow my algorithm.

```cpp
template <typename TYP> void quick_sort(TYP *tab, int poczatek, int koniec) {
  int i = poczatek;
  int j = poczatek;
  int srodek = (poczatek + koniec) / 2;
  int piwot = tab[srodek];

  swap(tab[srodek], tab[koniec]);

  for (i = poczatek; i < koniec; i++) {
    if (tab[i] < piwot) {
      swap(tab[i], tab[j]);
      j++;
    }
  }
  swap(tab[koniec], tab[j]);

  if (poczatek < j - 1)
    quick_sort(tab, poczatek, j - 1);

  if (j + 1 < koniec)
    quick_sort(tab, j + 1, koniec);
}
```

Comment: Could you also share the other algorithm? And how you are measuring the code? Specifically what inputs you are giving?

Comment: Quick sort has well-known conditions under which it behaves poorly. You don't appear to be taking steps to avoid those conditions.

Comment: Try to run the built-in C [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/) and see its timing, to get an idea if it's the algorithm hitting a degenerate case, or if it's your implementation that's broken.

Comment: 40 seconds seems quite slow for an array of 1000000 values anyway. What is the input type? Did you enable compiler optimisation flags?

Comment: `qsort` has no requirement that it actually use the quicksort algorithm.

Comment: my inputs code: `case 2:
start=clock();
for (int i=0; i<ile_tab; i++){
quick_sort<int>(tablica[i],poczatek,rozmiar-1);
 }
stop=clock();
czas=(double)(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

cout<<"czas:"<<czas<<"s"<<endl;
 this is my inputs, my array is alocating:int **tablica;
    tablica= new int*[ile_tab]; `

Answer (score 2):

The quick-sort has an average run-time of `O(n log(n))` but a worst-case complexity of **`O(n^2)` if the pivot is poorly chosen**. Regarding your input array, the pivot you choose can be really bad. To prevent this, you can implement an **[Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort)**. Moreover, you can use a better method to choose the pivot: the [median-of-three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) rule for example.

Moreover, **quick-sort is slow for small arrays**. You can significantly improve its performance using an **insertion-sort** for arrays smaller than 15 for example. The last recursive calls will be faster resulting in an overall faster execution.

Finally, your quick-sort use the Lomuto partition scheme which is probably not the most efficient. You can try to use the **Hoare's partition scheme**.